# Alsa Dmix wrong sample rate

Tags: alsa, linaro

I am trying to add a dix to my Alsa conf file, but when I playback using it the sample rate is wrong (it's too slow)

I have the following:

```
pcm.dmix0 {
type dmix
ipc_key 34521
slave {
    pcm "hw:0,0"
    format S16_LE
    rate 48000
}
    hint {
            description "DMix of Card0"
    }
}

pcm.asym51 {
       type asym
       playback.pcm "dmix0"
       capture.pcm "hw:0,0"
}
pcm.dsp0 {
     type plug
     slave.pcm "asym51"
}
```

When I play the audio back directly to the hardware, it plays fine, but I do miss a bit at the start.`aplay -D hw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`

When I use my dsp0 / dmix the rate is much slower than it should be:`aplay -D dsp0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the complete output of the `aplay` command?

Comment: linaro@linaro-alip:~/Desktop$ aplay -D hw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
linaro@linaro-alip:~/Desktop$ aplay -D dsp0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono

Comment: `linaro@linaro-alip:~/Desktop$ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
dmix0
    DMix of Card0
asym51
dsp0
Micsnoop
    Snoop of I2S_Mic
swapL
swapR
asym1
    Asym of Dmix1 and dsnoopRight
ASR
default:CARD=DB410c
    DB410c,
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=DB410c
    DB410c,
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=DB410c,DEV=0
    DB410c,
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=DB410c,DEV=0`

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the driver.

Comment: Is it the driver which implements the dmix?

Comment: No. But dmix is likely to use smaller buffer/period sizes than 'normal' playback.